# How to place a amazon product order through Alexa API

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build a Amazon Alexa Skill that allows users to find and order certain products on amazon.

Is there a way to order the products through amazon via the Alexa API or at least add them to the users Alexa 'Shopping list'?

Comment: Would the Amazon, Amazon-echo & Amazon-API tags be appropriate to add to the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The Alexa API only provides the ability to receive Intents based on what a user said and you can provide a spoken feedback, a card in the Alexa app, and do processing or make API calls to web services.  The Alexa platform provides no access for 3rd party developers to view or manage a users Amazon shopping experience.

I'm not aware of Amazon providing 3rd parties APIs to manage a users shopping experience.

However, the way you would use Alexa to manage a shopping experience like this would be to first use Alexa's OAuth 2.0 integration to authorize the skill to the shopping service.  Then when the users asks or tells Alexa something you'd be able to make API calls to look up products, add them to a shopping card, and complete a checkout process.

The issue with what you are asking is Amazon already provides this functionality natively on the Alexa platform, and like I mentioned I do not believe Amazon provides APIs to manage the shopping experience in the way you are talking about.  Even if Amazon provided these APIs I feel like this skill would be unlikely to get through the review process since Amazon already is providing a shopping experience on the Alexa platform.